# If a car ahead of me suddenly speeds up close to the speed of light, what would I and the car observe each of us?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, spacetime, time-dilation, spacetime-dimensions

Suppose I and the car is beside each other and the car went a little ahead of me, then instantly speeds up close to the speed of light. Will I observe the car is going too slow or stuck at one place and can I walk to the car to catch up with it despite its going at that speed? While, will the car see itself travelling at the speed of light but still couldn't pass me? The problem is what would happen to both of our observations if we are that close at distance and one of them suddenly travelling at the speed of light. I understand the further distance relativity like between space and earth but I'm really confused what would happen in this kind of scenario. Such as if I flip my one hand at the speed of light will I see it's going slow while the hand is feeling fast, just another example. I know it sounds crazy, anyone can still explain even in a critical way is fine. Also not taking infinite energy and mass into consideration.

Comment: Worth noting perhaps that if a car did this inside Earth's atmosphere, it would result in the nitrogen and oxygen within the atmosphere releasing enormous energies as they undergo nuclear fusion. You would not live long enough to see anything.

Answer (score 3):

If a car alongside you were to instantly accelerate to near the speed of light then it would seem to you to have disappeared instantly. Your eye takes more than 10 milliseconds to react to changing images- in that short time the car would already be about 3,000 kilometres away, and far too distant for you to see. You would not be able to walk up to the car.